# RenderScript Pragma Error

Tags: android, renderscript, pragma

I'm trying to use renderscript and it gives me the error that pragma name is not correct.I'm using pragma like this:

```
#pragma rs java_com.example.shahryar.ripplerenderscript
```

is it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form should be:

```
#pragma rs java_package_name(java_com.example.shahryar.ripplerenderscript)
```

Comment: Tnx. I figured it out.